# Jupyter cell stuck in process - interrupting cell allows the operation to be successful

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, jupyter-notebook, iteration

My calculation takes forever when the duration is supposed to be short (0.2 second). when I interrupt the cell, it allows to finish the process at 100%.

Context :

I want to verify that a value is in a dictionary, for that I iterate on the dictionary :

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < 9 :
    try :
        if dictionary[i] == "my_value" :
            j = i
            break
    except :
        i +=1
```

Where `j` is here to store the location of the key in the dictionary.

What happens is that it should take 0.2 seconds to process. However, it runs infinitely. If I interrupt the cell, two scenarios happen :

1. The interruption goes as expected
2. The interruption actually completes the operation and displays the result

Example : I print `i` at each step and I get :

*Running forever, frozen on a random number*

```
>>>0
>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
>>>4
>>>5
>>>6
>>>7
```

Then, when I interrupt the cell, I get :

```
>>>0
>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
>>>4
>>>5
>>>6
>>>7
>>>8
>>>9
>>>j = 2
```

aka the run of the cell is successful, I get the output that I expected. In conclusion, interrupting the cell allows the operation to be successful.

I do not understand what happens exactly, maybe the interruption exists a `try()` that was stuck.
The problem is that it is obviously not consistent at all to manually interrupt the cells (sometimes it really interrupts the cell without finishing the computation).

What causes the infinite run? How to fix the code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop is always checking the `if` condition, but because `i=0` is not going to change, the condition is always false and you are stuck in the loop forever

Try to add `i += 1` in the `try` block so that it will not stuck at `i=0`, like this:

```
dictionary = {1:'', 2:'', 3:'', 4:'', 99:'', 6:'my_value', 7:'', 8:'', 9:'', }

i = 0
j = 0
while i < 9 :
    try :
        if dictionary[i] == "my_value" :
            print(i, dictionary[i])
            break
        else:
            print(i)
        i +=1
    except :
        print('exception at', i)
        i +=1
```

Output

```
exception at 0
1
2
3
4
exception at 5
6 my_value
```

Comment: Indeed. my base case scenario was that the condition is always true or breaks the try, but actually there are 1% cases when it doesn't break it while being false.. thanks you
p.s. I am doing all this because my dictionary is more complicated than that, for example `dictionary["Information"][i]["Value"]...`

Comment: wow.. but that's not exactly very complicated.. only nested with 3 keys like `dict[k1][k2][k3]`

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer.. good luck to your coding!

Comment: not so complicated indeed, but that's the reason I used a `try`.
See : if I'm just looking for the number of the key, I can simply do :
`while i <  9:` 
`if dictionary[i] == "my value" :` 
`print(i)` 
`break`
`else :`
`i += 1` 
But since I have, for example `dictionary[i]["Value"]`
It can happen that the key simply does not exist in the dictionary. Then, when I try to access it, I get keyError. Hence the try as in my description.

Comment: Thanks to you for your answer, it solved my issue

Comment: Keep coding... Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

### Value in dictionary

To know if a value is in a dictionary use:

```
is_in = "your_value" in your_dict.values()
```

### Key of your value

The previous function only tells if a value is in a dictionary but not the key to that value. To know the key you can do a loop:

```
your_key = ""
for key, value in your_dict.items():
    if value == "your_value":
        your_key = key
        break
```

Also you can use lists to find the key:

```
list(your_dict.keys())[list(your_dict.values()).index("your_value")]
```

My recomendation is to always search for a build in function before writing a loop. Most of the times there is one that does the job ;)

### Infinite loop

Note that you only increment the variable `i` if an exception happens.

No exception -> No increment of `i` -> No exception

Comment: Definitely a good lesson. Thanks ! I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: you have my vote as well! cheers! :-)